# ubuntu 18.04+ not checking /etc/hosts why does etc hosts updates no longer work? How to update /etc/hosts

Tags: networking, dns

Why does updating /etc/hosts no longer work?

How can I debug and get it to work?

`cat /etc/hosts:`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost

# I added this line
127.0.0.1   kakfa
```

`cat /etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

`cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search lan
```

`systemd-resolve --status`:

```
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp3s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp0s20f3)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
        DNS Domain: lan
```

related:

- [/etc/hosts not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154254/etc-hosts-not-working)
- [local DNS lookup not working, despite everything is in /etc/hosts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582177/local-dns-lookup-not-working-despite-everything-is-in-etc-hosts)
- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/resolvconf.conf.5.html
- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html

Comment: You have not adequately asked any question. What did you add to your hosts file? What was the expected result? What was the eventual incorrect result?

Comment: Read `man systemd-dnsmasq` and `man 5 hosts`

Answer (score 0):

I put two lines for 127.0.0.1

It should have been

```
127.0.0.1   localhost     kakfa
::1     localhost
```